# Case change for Schema generation using Hibernate Naming Strategy

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I am creating ddl from hibernate hbm2ddl tool facility.

I have many to one relationship SensorInterfaceConfCalibration.java class while generating ddl it generates fine for other tables but it generates small calibration_id in

```
CREATE TABLE SEN_INT_CONF_CALIB(calibration_id numeric(19,0) null, SENSOR_INTERFACE_CONF_ID numeric(19,0) not null...etc...)
```

I am returning the table and column names in caps using namingstrategy.java

I am using hibernate version 3.5.0

Comment: I am using the above generated schema for SQL Server But as it has case sensitive collation, It is causing problems for SQL Server related Tests.. PLease help if anyone gone under this....

Answer (score 0):

Ohh... Resolved problem..
Actually I had to add the @Table(name='SEN_INT_CONF_CALIB') rather than @ join Table